# NodeJS - where to place functions for eval()

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have a NodeJS-Server which communicated with the fronend via Websocket-Connection.

When the Server gets a `on('message')`, it should run a function which name is given the message via `eval()`.

it workes fine, unless I completely don't know where to put the funcions to be called.

```
var http = require('http');
var ws = require('ws');

function render(vars)  {  
    var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
        .....
    });

    /* WEBSOCKET */
    var wsServer = new ws.Server({server});
    wsServer.on('connection', socket => { 
      socket.on('message', message => {
        console.log('WS from template <-- ', message);
        var wsIn = JSON.parse(message);        
        eval(wsIn.action);   
    });    
 });  

}
```

when a message is incoming, `eval(wsIn.action)` should run a function called.. .lets assume `runme`.. so where would I now need to declare this function ? I try everything but whatever I do, i get

> ReferenceError:: runme is not defined

edit:

I found out something interesting:
when i call a function normal like `runme();` in my `onMessage`.. everything is cool.. but with `eval(runme);` nothing happens.. no error, no output, nothing..

Comment: Just put it after the render() function. Or above it. The `eval()` runs on the server, so that's the scope in which the function needs to be defined.

Comment: You'll probably have to define a global function: global.runme = () => { /* some code */}

Comment: You should probably consider an alternate approach, as running eval on the server is very dangerous. How about just making an object of the name of the function to function. ex: `{ fnA: () => console.log('a') }` so on message it can just see it it is in the dictionary and evaluate it.

Comment: that is somehow wierd.. when I define this function with a simple `console.log()` in it before/after the `render()`.. i get no error, but still the function says nothing where it should say hello through console.log()

Comment: What is your exact code, and what is the contents of `wsIn.action`?

Comment: @chris G .. `wsIn.action` is simply a string `runMe`

Comment: Are you sure you even need `eval()`? It's a last resort, especially if you're feeding client-side stuff into it. Make sure this isn't an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), what is your goal here?

Comment: @ChrisG .. I need to run a function dynamicly, depending on what the client wants from the server..

Comment: @Arschibald I get that. But I assume "what the client wants" is not an infinite amount of possible actions? But more likely a limit set of actions and some parameters for each? Can you give an EXAMPLE? *ANYTHING FOR US TO WORK WITH, WHILE WE'RE HELPING YOU FOR FREE?*

Comment: @ChrisG .. sure.. I have a server that delivers content to the client..  some user might click on a button.. e.g. "update-container-x-with-content-of-blaaah" .. it now sends the functionname and the params to the server, which should execute the needed function and deliver back its resullt to the client...  so far so good..  but in fact, the amount of functions the server should be able to execute IS infinite .. I do not want to define every function i add...  the server should work full dynamicly here.. therefor i took eval()

Comment: You said `when a message is incoming, eval(wsIn.action) should run a function called.. [...] runme` so how are you planning on writing infinite functions into your backend...? Eval() doesn't magically turn your server into an actual AI. To me it looks like you're going to have `function updateContainer(containerID, newContent)` and a few other, similar functions.

Comment: @chrisG .. your comments made me think about it again and again.. I now have a - i think better - solution.. btw.. the solution for the problem in the main-post is `eval(wsIn.action)()` instead of `eval(wsIn.action)`.. but I I now have outsourced te code in seperate lib-files, where every file have a main index-method.. i now require the file dynamicly and run the index-function... just like in a MVC in PHP